Bigquery and Coursera data analytics course 5 module 3 error with table name
I have followed the instructions but keep getting an error with the following code spelled out in the lesson:
SELECT
employees.name as employee_name,
employees.role as employee_role,
departments.name as department_name
FROM 'daq5bigquery.employee_data.employees' AS employees
INNER JOIN daq5bigquery.employee_data.departments AS departments
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
I keep getting an error on the second table after INNER JOIN.
I have tried doing the code from different perspectives. it does not like the table name and I don't known how to fix it.

Welcome and good luck with the course!
As it appears to me, you have wrapped the name of the second table with a single quote (marked as '), which makes your expression a string literal.
Please note the following types of quote characters in BigQuery and their usage:

Single Quotes(') and Double Quotes(") are used to represent string literals, or just plain text, that is a value to be stored or used somehow.
Backticks (`) are used to represent forms of "entities" in your database, rather than values. They can be used to reference/rename columns and tables.

Taking that into consideration, your query should look like this:
SELECT 
  employees.name as employee_name,
  employees.role as employee_role,
  departments.name as department_name 
FROM `daq5bigquery.employee_data.employees` AS employees
INNER JOIN `daq5bigquery.employee_data.departments` AS departments
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id

Also, for future reference, note that BigQuery lets you know of the error you are facing, in an error message.
In the case of running your original query, the error message that is printed by BigQuery is:

Syntax error: Unexpected string literal
'daq5bigquery.employee_data.employees' at [1:115]

Specifying your error message in your post, or searching for it online, will guarantee you will get your assistance faster and in a more accurate manner.
